# SyntaxError: Unexpected token import in Angular 2 Universal when using 3rd party modules

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webpack, universal

Hi I am getting a SyntaxError when I run server.ts after ng build for Angular Universal (npm start look at package.json).

This only happens if I run server.ts and only if I am using a third party modules like Angularitics2 or AdsenseModule. ng serve works perfectly fine. I think it has something to do with ng build and transpiling.

I followed this tutorial in order to make the Universal work.: 
https://coursetro.com/posts/code/68/Make-your-Angular-App-SEO-Friendly-

Error in console:

```
[root@mainframe core]$ ts-node src/server.ts
/var/www/uni-app/core/node_modules/angulartics2/dist/core/angulartics2.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.coreInThisContext (vm.js:78:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/uni-app/core/dist/ngfactory/src/app/app.server.module.ngfactory.ts:32:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
```

App.module.ts

```
import { Angulartics2Module, Angulartics2GoogleTagManager} from 'angulartics2';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    Angulartics2Module.forRoot([ Angulartics2GoogleTagManager]),
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routes,
```

server.ts

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import { platformServer, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server'
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core'
import { AppServerModuleNgFactory } from '../dist/ngfactory/src/app/app.server.module.ngfactory'
import * as express from 'express';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';

const PORT = 4000;

enableProdMode();

const app = express();

let template = readFileSync(join(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'index.html')).toString();

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  const opts = { document: template, url: options.req.url };

  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, opts)
    .then(html => callback(null, html));
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', 'src')

app.get('*.*', express.static(join(__dirname, '..', 'dist')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`listening on http://192.168.33.77:${PORT}!`);
});
```

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "core",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "ng build --prod && ngc && webpack",
    "start": "ts-node src/server.ts"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angulartics2": "^2.2.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "ng2-adsense": "^2.2.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1",
    "gulp-connect": "~2.3.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "~2.4.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "~1.0.2",
    "gulp-ruby-sass": "~2.0.6",
    "gulp-uglyfly": "~1.4.2",
    "gulp-order": "~1.1.1",
    "gulp-concat": "~2.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "~2.0.0",
    "gulp-util": "~3.0.7",
    "gulp-clean-css": "3.0.3",
    "gulp-sequence": "^0.4.6",
    "webpack": "~2.2.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.5.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Check if you have a service file and post its content . The error says a syntax error in some service file .. `Injectable`

Comment: Not sure what service file you mean. I havent even used anything from the angularitics module inside a service or compontent. Except for importing it into the app.module.ts. Or do you mean the contents of the module itself which is inside the node_modules folder. https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2

Comment: No, not in `node_modeules` search in your project if `Injectable` used anywhere

Comment: None. You can duplicate the problem by using this project and importing angularitics. https://github.com/designcourse/angular-seo/tree/master/src also where does it say the problem is inside a service?

Comment: { import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';                                                                         
   ^^^^^^

Comment: I will follow the tutorial , can you tell which step you are getting the error

Comment: So the error only popups if i import any third party module. So after you have setup the project from the github link. (npm install) 

I just import the angularitics 2 module inside the app.module.ts. Also not forget (npm install angulartics2) 

After that i run npm start. It will build the app into dist folder and run server.ts and webpack afterwards. And thats when the error comes in.

Comment: I could reproduce the issue :) , will look into it

Comment: Ok thanks hope you can find an answer. :)

Comment: The problem is , the external library is in typescript. Our build is expecting it to be javascript. Checking how to tell it consider it as typescript and compile

Comment: I tried for 2 hours, am not expert in how build system work , so sorry  . cant help. Lets wait for an expert to fix it

Comment: @Skeptor ok I'll try and see if I can find a fix in the meantime. Thanks for the effort really appreciate it :) Hopefully someone else can find a solution.